# Galleria works locally in all browsers but only IE8 & Chrome when hosted

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8, host, galleria

This page:
http://www.ipjnet.talktalk.net/code/photos.html
works in Opera11,Chrome, Firefox3 & IE8 locally.

The same page hosted only loads correctly in IE8 & Chrome

I'm new to galleria and jquery so please be gentle with me as I think I must be missing something very obvious.

Thank You very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes in your script files are the wrong ones...

```
<script src="galleria\src\jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="galleria\src\galleria.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="galleria/src/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="galleria/src/galleria.js"></script>
```

IE on the "local" machine, (and hosted in Quirks mode) let you get away with this.  However on the "Web" the path delimiters are forward slashes only.

As a result of the wrong slashes, jQuery and the Galleria don't load at all in Firefox/(other browsers)

Comment: Thanks, absolutely right and a good explanation. Very embarrasing too!

Comment: @Jonesi - no worries at all! I'd give your site a regular check with Firefox/other browsers before "going live".  You'll be amazed how many things IE will "let" you get away with that other browsers will simply reject.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="galleria\src\jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script src="galleria\src\galleria.js"></script>
```

should be (forward slash, not back slash)

```
    <script src="galleria/src/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script src="galleria/src/galleria.js"></script>
```

surprising it works in chrome...

Comment: Yes I was surprised by Chrome being less troublesome. Thank you for taking the trouble to respond.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is not being sourced.

I'm guessing firefox doesn't like the backslashes, try forward slashes.

```
<script src="galleria/src/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="galleria/src/galleria.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh! Talk about can't see the wood for the trees! That was so obvious.  Thanks very much for pointing it - fixed.